# How should I test request-related logic in Rails development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have several before_filters defined in my application controller to handle requests I don't like. One representative example is:

```
before_filter :reject_www

private

def reject_www
  if request.subdomains.include? 'www'
    redirect_to 'http://example.com' + request.path, :status => 301
    false
  end
end
```

(Returning false skips any following before_filters and simply returns the redirection immediately)

So, two questions:

One, how should I test this functionality? The only testing framework I've used so far is Cucumber + Webrat, which isn't really set up to handle this kind of thing. Is there another framework I should also use to fake requests like this?

Two, is there any way I can try out this functionality myself in my development environment? Since I'm simply browsing the site at localhost:3000, I can't ensure that the above code works in my browser - I'd have to push it to production, hope it works and hope it doesn't mess up anything for anyone in the meantime, which makes me nervous. Is there an alternative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a functional test, you can explicitly set the request host. I'm not sure what testing framework you prefer, so here is an example in good ole' Test::Unit.

```
def test_should_redirect_to_non_www
  @request.host = 'www.mydomain.com'
  get :index
  assert_redirected_to 'http://mydomain.com/'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

To address #2 
You can add entries in your hosts file so that  www.mydomain.com points to your local host and then test the logic in your development environment  . 
You can try hosting it using passenger so that it works on apache . 
Hope that helps .